# Multiple configurations for JAX-B

Tags: java, configuration, annotations, jaxb

We have the problem that we have to generate different XML-Representations for the same JAVA Object.

E.g. we have a User-Class, that contains confidential information, like lastLoginDate or birthday.

- For archiving we need a complete XML-representation with lastLoginDate
  and birthday .
- However for data exchange with external partners, we do not want to
  include this confidential information.

So the object is always the same, however we want to marshal it to one XML-representation in one context and into another XML-representation in another context.

```
@XmlType
public class UserData implements UserInfoBean {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Timestamp lastLogin;

    @XmlAttribute(required = false)
    public Timestamp getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }

    public void setLastLogin(Timestamp lastLogin) {
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstname) {
        this.firstName = truncate(firstname, 50);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastname) {
        this.lastName = truncate(lastname, 80);
    }
    ...
}
```

Currently we use java-annotation to configure the XML in detail. However we have not found any way to provide two different jaxb-configurations.

Thank you

Wallenstein

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to address this.

The easiest is probably to use MOXy [XML Bindings](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/moxy/runtime003.htm). You can have several bindings and create `JAXBContext` with one or the other version:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream iStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("metadata/normal-xml-bindings.xml");

Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, iStream);

JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { Customer.class }, properties);
```

Alternatively you could also write a custom annotation reader and use it when creating the `JAXBContext`. This custom annotation reader could, for instance, suppress certain properties if a certain additional annotation is present.

```
public class CustomAnnotationReader extends
        AbstractInlineAnnotationReaderImpl<Type, Class, Field, Method>
        implements RuntimeAnnotationReader { ... }

// ....

final RuntimeAnnotationReader annotationReader = new CustomAnnotationReader();

        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        properties.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, annotationReader);

        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
                contextPath, Thread.currentThread()
                        .getContextClassLoader(), properties);
```

I personally would probably go with a custom annotation reader - this would allow staying with annotations (instead of XML bindings).

Comment: Hello lexicore, the second alternative with a custom annotation reader sound cool. I will give it a try.